# .NET How can I send an email message where it will popup upon receipt without having outlook installed on the server?

Tags: .net, email, outlook, smtp

Right now I have a vb.net program that use sends a mail to users with the follow-up date set to a date in the past so that it will pop up a past due notification as soon as the recipient receives the email.

```
Dim objMailItem As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem
objMailItem.FlagStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlFlagStatus.olFlagMarked        
objMailItem.FlagDueBy = BackDate                                       
objMailItem.FlagIcon = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlFlagIcon.olRedFlagIcon            
objMailItem.FlagRequest = "Follow Up"                                  
objMailItem.ReminderSet = True                                         
objMailItem.ReminderPlaySound = True
```

However to do this we have to have outlook installed on the server sending the mail, and have outlook open. Is there a way to set this without having outlook installed? The end result would have the recipient receive the mail and it show up flagged and his list of tasks with a due date in the past so that it shows up as red and past due in the Outlook reminder notification popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to set Outlook-specific properties (like flags, categories, reminders, etc.) on emails that you send is to:

- Use the Outlook Object Model (Outlook needs to be installed)
- Use Exchange Web Services
- Use Microsoft Graph or the Outlook Mail REST API
- Code your solution in C++ using Extended MAPI
- Code your solution using Redemption

The last two require only the [standalone version of MAPI](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1004) to be installed.